# How to do stream sort based on multiple comparsions of nested object?

Tags: java, collections, java-stream

Model example:

I need to sort stream of cars based on gender of the driver and then his age.

```
public class Car {
    String color;
    Driver driver; 
}
```

```
public class Driver {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    String gender;  
}
```

```
public List<Car> sortCars(List<Car> cars) {
    return cars.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator
                .comparing(car -> -1 /* car.getDriver().getGender() */ )
                .thenComparing(car -> -1 /* car.getDriver().getAge() */ ))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I do not want to create special Comparator classes or implement Comparator interfaces. Is my use case even possible? I've been browsing SO for the past hour and none of the answers work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the type inference isn't strong enough. This worked for me:

```
return cars.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(car -> ((Car) car).getDriver().getGender())
                .thenComparingInt(car -> ((Car) car).getDriver().getAge()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Don't use cast, it prevents type safety. Instead, specify the parameter type: `Comparator.comparing((Car car) -> car.getDriver().getGender())`. or specify the type parameter: `Comparator.<Car, String>comparing(car -> car.getDriver().getGender())`

Comment: @Andreas I've seen and tried this solution, but it didn't work for some reason. Tried it again and now there are no complaints in IDE, thank you! I really like your solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Kartik works. But if you want to avoid casting, you have two more options:

Option 1:

```
 Comparator<Car> com1 = Comparator.comparing(car -> car.getDriver().getGender());
 Comparator<Car> com2 = Comparator.comparing(car -> car.getDriver().getAge());
```

then:

```
cars.stream().sorted(com1.thenComparing(com2)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Option 2:

Let the compiler know you are comparing `Car`s:

```
cars.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing((Car car) -> car.getDriver().getGender())
    .thenComparing(car -> car.getDriver().getAge()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

*EDIT:* Actually, you have even more options. Per @Andreas' comment, you can pass the type by `Comparator.<Car, String>comparing` or you can just write your own `comparing` function which will look like:

```
sorted((car1, car2) -> {/*function body that returns -1, 0, 1 */}
```

Also, if you have a `List<Car>` you want to sort, you can directly use `sort()` method:

```
cars.sort(com1.thenComparing(com2));
```

Comment: You don't have to specify the parameter type in `thenComparing`.

Comment: I actually used `sorted((car1, car2) -> {/*function body that returns -1, 0, 1 */}` as a temporary workaround. Option 1 makes sense in the cases, where you need to reuse the comparators, but that was not my case unfortunately.

Comment: @TomášMrázek  You don't have to define a global scope for `com1` and `com2` if you don't want to use them outside of a local scope. In any case, I think this is more readable than casting and unlike casting, it is type safe.