# Filtering data based on two conditions in java streams

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code

```
public class Car {
    Long carNum;
    String carEngine;
}
```

The data in List object is as follows:

```
Car(carNum=1, carEngine=S02K), 
Car(carNum=1, carEngine=null), 
Car(carNum=2, carEngine=null),
Car(carNum=2, carEngine=S9K),
Car(carNum=3, carEngine=null)
```

How can I filter out data from the car object where

check for **distinct carNum** If there are more than one similar carNum then check where **carEngine is not null** and return the data in a list.

I am able to do the distinct carNum using

```
public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
        Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
        return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
}
```

in the following way:

```
carList.stream().filter(distinctByKey(Car::getCarNum)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above code gets the distinct carNum but there is a very good chance that it will return the results with null carEngine.

How can I check where carEngine is not null along with distinct carNum combined.

**NOTE:** If there is only one distinct carNum without carEngine then I should return that row along with other rows.

For example: If the input data looks like this:

```
Car(carNum=1, carEngine=S02K), 
Car(carNum=1, carEngine=null), 
Car(carNum=2, carEngine=null),
Car(carNum=2, carEngine=S9K),
Car(carNum=3, carEngine=null)
```

then the output should be:

```
Car(carNum=1, carEngine=S02K), 
Car(carNum=2, carEngine=S9K),
Car(carNum=3, carEngine=null)
```

Please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: You can't pass a null to an  int in the constructor  carCode is an int.  Please include your complete class including constructors and getters.  And why is the car name an int?  If is really a string, any answer provided won't be of use to you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I corrected them.

Comment: I removed unnecessary properties from the class in the question.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the `toMap()` collector with a merge function to select the one with a non-null engine:

```
carList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                Collectors.toMap(
                        Car::getCarNum,
                        c -> c,
                        (a, b) -> a.getCarEngine() != null ? a : b),
                map -> new ArrayList<>(map.values())))
```

This way, if there's a `carNum` with only null engines, the first one will remain the final result.

Answer (score 2):

Predicates provide the method [`and()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html#and(java.util.function.Predicate)), which allows you to combine two predicates with a logical **AND**.

> Returns a composed predicate that represents a short-circuiting logical AND of this predicate and another. When evaluating the composed predicate, if this predicate is false, then the other predicate is not evaluated.

Example:

```
Predicate<Car> distinctByCarNum = distinctByKey(Car::getCarNum);
Predicate<Car> engineNonNull = car -> Objects.nonNull(car.getCarEngine());
Predicate<Car> combinedPredicate = distinctByCarNum.and(engineNonNull);
List<Car> filtered = carList.stream()
    .filter(combinedPredicate)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Edit:** After requirement update, you need grouping, not filtering. Refer to the [answer from shmosel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76114896/17795888) for correct solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am sorry I edited the question couple of minutes back by explaining the scenario in a much detailed way. I should consider engineNonNull condition only if there are more than one carNum else I should just check only for distinctCarNum and return that value irrespective of the value of engine because there is a very good chance of engine being null and only one distinct carNum exists in the list. So, I should be returning that as well in the list.

Comment: @Vamsi If i understand correctly, you want `engineNonNull` to be applied only if there are at least 2 cars with distinct car numbers?

Comment: I want engineNonNull condition to be applied only if there are at least two cars with the same carNum. else just distinctkey alone should be applied

Comment: In simple terms I want the `engineNonNull` condition to be applied only if there are at least two cars with the same carNum else I should just apply distinct Key

Comment: @Vamsi In that case, what you need is more akin to grouping, not filtering - i don't think it's possible with a filter anyway. Refer to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76114896/17795888) from shmosel, it does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way.

- first I group by `carNum`.
- then for each collection of same `carNums` I first check that all are null for `carEngine`.  If so, I simply return the first in the collection.
- otherwise, I stream the list and choose the first one that is not null since one **must** be.

```
List<Car> results = carList.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Car::getCarNum)).values()
   .stream().map(lst -> {
      if (lst.stream().allMatch(car -> car.getCarEngine() == null)) {
          return lst.get(0);
      } else {
          return lst.stream()
                 .filter(car -> car.getCarEngine() != null)
                 .findFirst().get();
            }
        }).toList();
```

prints

```
Car [carNum=1, carEngine=S02K]
Car [carNum=2, carEngine=S9K]
Car [carNum=3, carEngine=null]
```

Comment: You can use `.allMatch(...)` instead of `.filter(...).count() == lst.size()`. But really this would much cleaner as a simple loop and `Map.merge()`.

Comment: @shmosel Yeah.  My big stumbling point (imho) was ensuring I took a valid value over null but null if that was the only choice.  You solved that problem rather elegantly using reduce.

Comment: I should mention `allMatch()` is also more efficient, since it'll short-circuit as soon as it finds a mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

### Sort with [`nullsLast`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast(java.util.Comparator)) before filtering

The trick is to sort with **nulls last** before the distinct-filter:

```java
// first by number
Comparator.comparing(Car::getNum)
  // we prefer with engine before no engine.
  .thenComparing(Car::getEngine, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
```

You can pass this comparator to the `Stream.sorted()` step, before filtering.

#### Solution

```java
import java.util.*
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

class Car {
  int num;
  String engine;

  public Car(int num, String engine) {
    this.num = num;
    this.engine = engine;
  }

  public Integer getNum() {
    return this.num;
  }

  public String getEngine() {
    return this.engine;
  }

  public String toString() {
    return String.format("Car: %d, %s", num, engine);
  }
}

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {
  public static <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKey(
      Function<? super T, ?> keyExtractor) {
    Set<Object> seen = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();
    return t -> seen.add(keyExtractor.apply(t));
  }

  public static Comparator<Car> withNullEnginesLast() {
    return Comparator.comparing(Car::getNum)
        .thenComparing(
            Car::getEngine, Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.naturalOrder()));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    // your code goes here

    var carList = List.of(
        // num, engine
        new Car(1, "S02K"),
        new Car(1, null),  // filter out as duplicate (nulls last)
        new Car(2, null),  // filter out as duplicate (nulls last)
        new Car(2, "S9K"),
        new Car(3, null)  // include because only occurrence for number
    );

    var result =
        carList.stream()
            .sorted(withNullEnginesLast()) // sort first by num, then engine
                                           // where null-engines last
            .filter(distinctByKey(Car::getNum))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println(result);
  }
}
```

Prints the car 2 **with engine**:

```
[Car: 1, S02K, Car: 2, S9K, Car: 3, null]
```

Try it online: [IDEone demo](https://ideone.com/69nfTx)

#### See also

- Baeldung Tutorial: [Java 8 - Comparison with Lambdas](https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-sort-lambda)
- Similar Car sorting: [How to do stream sort based on multiple comparsions of nested object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58332511/how-to-do-stream-sort-based-on-multiple-comparsions-of-nested-object)
- JavaDocs for the important decorator: [`Comparator.nullsLast()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsLast(java.util.Comparator))

Comment: The asked "2 conditions" are implemented in 2 consecutive steps: (1) order by "carEngine is not null" first, (2) filter by "distinct carNum".